# Supplying component for a CDK Overlay in 2 different ways

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, angular-content-projection

I've got an interesting situation for our component library that we just can't fully solve.

We have a component called `banner` that can show as a warning or info inline in the app.

We'd also like to be able to show this `banner` as an overlay `toast` type of experience but reuse the same component.

We want to be able to supply it to a service in 2 different ways, one is directly from a template of any component that has a reference to it.  And the other is by referencing the Component import.

For the first way the best way we came up with is to have a wrapper element `banner-overlay`

The template of this wrapping component looks like this:

```
<ng-template #foo>
  <div class="banner-overlay">
    <ng-content select="banner[type=warning]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The `ts` file looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'banner-overlay',
  templateUrl: './banner-overlay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner-overlay.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule, PortalModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class BannerOverlayComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('foo', { static: true }) tmpl!: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(public vcr: ViewContainerRef) {}

}
```

It can be used like this in a given template:

```
<banner-container #container>
  <banner >
    Projected content
  </banner>
</banner-container>
```

The the `ts` file can grab it:

```
@ViewChild('container', { static: true })
  bannerOverlay!: BannerOverlayComponent;
```

Once we need to display the already referenced Overlay we can call the service with this method:

```
createBanner(item: BannerOverlayComponent) {
    const overlayRef = this._createOverlay();

    const portal = new TemplatePortal(item.tmpl, item.vcr);

    overlayRef.attach(portal);
  }
```

This works and feels pretty good and straight forward for other devs.

Where we are struggling is how to have a component such as FooBannerOverlay with a template like this:

```
<banner>
   projected content
</banner>
```

With the intent being that a developer can pass in a reference to this component class and not have to go put this in a template and then grab the reference to the template but that it could try to do some lifting for the dev and auto-wrap it with the BannerOverlay component. Then it could utilize CDK ComponentPortal/TemplatePortal to generate the portal.

I've tried lots of things with the new `createComponent` stuff.  It kind of worked but content projection was wonky and felt very un-Angular to be supplying native nodes.

Any ideas or things I haven't thought of?